# Any way to retrieve phone number from incoming sms in autopilot

Tags: python, twilio, sms, chatbot, twilio-autopilot

I am creating a Twilio Autopilot program that works on the SMS channel. Currently, I set up the sms channel using the messaging URL and webhooks according to the instructions in the SMS setup section here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-build-a-chatbot.
This works, but I am trying to find a way to retrieve the phone number from the incoming SMS to try and match it to a user to provide context to the bot ahead of time. Is there any way to accomplish this?
I am coding this in Python but any advice would be appreciated regardless of language.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Autopilot webhook request is documented here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request) and shows the parameters that are sent with each request.

In this case, you are looking for the `UserIdentifier` parameter in the incoming request, which, in the case of voice or SMS channels, will be the user's phone number.

Note that the request is made in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Comment: Thanks for the response @philnash, I totally overlooked that. After grabbing the request data, I get it in the form of a MultiDict, where the nested dictionaries are just a string. Like this:
{"key": "{key2: {key3 : val3}}", "key4": "val4"} where "{key2: {key3 : val3}}" is an entire string.
Is there any way to convert this to a json, or parse it more easily?

Comment: The `Memory` parameter is sent as a JSON string, and you will need to parse that yourself. You can do so with the built in `json` module and `json.loads` method.